# AWS CDK: Using SecurityGroup construct with CfnVpc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have very specific IP addressing requirements for my VPC. I have 4 CIDR blocks, where 4 subnets (in 3 AZs) need to be in main first block and 1 subnet (in 3 AZs) need to be in each of the additional CIDR block.

For this reason I have to use `CfnVPC` to set it up correctly as the `Vpc` construct only accepts a subnet configuration which uses a mask to split it equally rather than accept a specific range for each subnet.

This is fine but now I'm looking at Security Groups and would really like to use the `SecurityGroup` construct as it has lots of syntactic sugar for adding rules like `addIngressRule`.

However this construct accepts the `IVPC` type which my manually created VPC isn't of this type.

Am I going to loose out on all the goodness of the aws-cdk constructs because my VPC is created manually? Seems like silly limitation.

**Does anyone know a way around this without me having to implement these methods myself?**

**Is it possible to achieve my VPC configuration using the `Vpc` construct?**

I need something like:

```
const vpc = Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'VPC', {
      vpcName: vpcStack.vpc.ref,
    });
```

But something that can take a non-concrete token as I still want the option to deploy everything at the same time.

Comment: I also meet the same problem. Is there an answer to this question?